# Выборка из базы данных Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Добрый день. Есть две модели:

Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function childCategories () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Child_category');
    }
}
```

Child_category

```
class Child_category extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Задача выбрать и все категории, и все дочерние категории для каждой из категорий.

У меня это реализовано форичем с добавлением поля childs, в котором содержатся все дочерние категории :

```
 $categories = Category::all();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category['childs'] = $category
            ->find($category['id'])
            ->childCategories()
            ->get();
    }
```

Вопрос: верный ли это подход?

Comment: у вас неправильное описание модели. Для модели не должно быть разницы между `Category` и `Child_category` (и боже мой, используйте CamelCase). Ну и как-то кода у вас много, так достаточно `$category->childCategories`.

Comment: Это модели для двух таблиц, а за совет благодарю

Comment: Вы правильно поняли, таблица должна быть одна - категория с полем для указания родителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы остановились на варианте, когда категории и подкатегории будут храниться в разных таблицах (для каждой из этих сущностей будет отдельная модель) и определили отношения, то никакого foreach вам не нужно.

Каждый раз, когда вы будете обращаться к свойству childCategories объекта модели Category Eloquent автоматически загрузит из базы необходимые данные.

Если вы хотите, чтобы подкатегории были загружены сразу, делайте так:

```
$categories = Category::with('childCategories')->get();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не могли бы с еще одни моментом помочь: 
   ``$categories = Category::with([ 'childCategories' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name');

        }])->select('id', 'name') `` 
            
Не работает проблема в   ``$query->select('id', 'name');``  - возвращает пустую коллекцию .

Comment: `$query->select()` обязательно должна содержать в данном случае столбец, по которому связывается подкатегория с категорией, иначе Eloquent не сможет связать объекты.